# Различные хедеры в одном php-файле

Tags: php

Есть файл index.php, который принимает все запросы и каждый запрос обрабатывает колбэком.

```
require 'flight/Flight.php';

Flight::route('GET /', function () {
    Flight::render('home', array('body_class' => 'frontpage'));
});

Flight::route('GET /images', function(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());
        $db = null;
        echo $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
});

Flight::start();

function getConnection()
{
    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);        
    return $dbh;
}
```

Могу ли я в каждом из колбэков задать свой хэдер? Например во втором руте мне нужен JSON, а в первом HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путем эксперимента выяснил, что можно в одном файле писать несколько хедеров. В данном случае во втором колбэке я могу установить хэдер на application/json, во всех остальных случаях будет просто text/html по умолчанию.

Comment: То, что вы написали код, еще не означает, что он выполнится. Все, что лежит внутри невызванных функций и блоков кода, чьи условия не были удовлетворены, выполнено не будет, и, насколько понимаю, вообще не сможет никоим образом повлиять на ход выполнения программы.